# Enable GPU for Spacy

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, spacy, spacy-transformers

I'm trying to set up a GPU to train models using Spacy

I've configured a docker container with GPU and it seems like it can be seen from Pytorch
[image]

Following the [spacy site](https://spacy.io/usage), to enable GPU I run the command

```
pip install -U 'spacy[cuda-autodetect]'
```

It fails saying it doesn't detect CUDA

[image]

If I run the PyTorch [collect_env](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py) script this is what I get
[image]

If I don't try to install this library and run
`spacy.prefer_gpu` I get a `False`

I'm not sure what could be missing

As a side note, I can use the GPU with other libraries like transformers

[image]

Comment: What is your cuda version?

Comment: it's cuda 11.4.3

Comment: Try `pip install -U spacy[cuda114]`

Comment: It installs the package but spacy.prefer_gpu returns False, If I try to install cuda-autodetect afterward, it fails again

Answer (score 1):

Try `spacy.require_gpu()` which provides information why gpu is not available. For example:

[image]